# Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: punc (.) when running bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

(Rails 5.2.6, Ruby 2.7.2)
When running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace`, I get the error `Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: punc (.)`.

In `config/environments/production.rb`, I have `config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)` but the issue persists

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke yarn:install (first_time)
** Execute yarn:install
yarn install v1.22.17
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
✨  Done in 0.06s.
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
Uglifier::Error: Unexpected token: punc (.)
--
 799         let val = offset[side];
 800         if (
 801           !isString(val) ||
 802           (val.indexOf('%') === -1 && val.indexOf('px') === -1)
 803         ) {
 804           val += 'px';
 805         }
 806 
  =>         if (this.markers[type] && this.markers[type].dot?.style[side] !== val) {
 808           this.markers[type].dot.style[side] = val;
 809         }
 810       }
 811     }
 812 
 813     return true;
 814   }
 815 });
==
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/uglifier-4.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:291:in `parse_result'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/uglifier-4.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:221:in `run_uglifyjs'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/uglifier-4.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:166:in `compile'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/compressing.rb:65:in `block in js_compressor='
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy_proc_processor.rb:31:in `call'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:186:in `compile'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:484:in `exec'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:103:in `with_friendly_errors'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.5/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/Users/jacksonvaldez/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.